# Значение слова "мил-моя"

Tags: языкознание

Что означает "мил-моя", и в каких случаях оно употребляется?

Answer (score 1):

Милая моя. ТАкое употребление характерно для устной речи. Возможно, еще местные особенности произношения накладываются.